# Open a popup at the loading of the map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I created a map with [OpenLayers](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers-js.html). Everything work great!
But I need to open a popup by default on the map loading, but I can't figure how.
Since I create and destroy the popup on the fly, I tried to simulate the click on the pin, but it didn't worked.
Anyone have an idea?
**Code**

```
function createMap() {
  var options = { 
     theme: null 
  }; 
  map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options); 
  map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM()); 
  epsg4326 =  new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'); 
  projectTo = map.getProjectionObject(); 
  var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(mark.longitude, mark.latitude).transform(epsg4326, projectTo); 
  var zoom = 15; 
  map.setCenter(lonLat, zoom); 
  var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('Overlay'); 

  for(x=0; x<stores.length; x++) {
    var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
      new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(stores[x].lon, stores[x].lat).transform(epsg4326, projectTo), 
      {description: stores[x].desc}, 
      {externalGraphic: 'marker.png', graphicHeight: 40, graphicWidth: 20, graphicXOffset: -10, graphicYOffset: -20}
    ); 
    vectorLayer.addFeatures(feature); 
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer); 
  };

  var controls = { 
    selector: new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectorLayer, { 
      onSelect: createPopup, 
      onUnselect: destroyPopup 
    }) 
  };

  map.addControl(controls['selector']); 
  controls['selector'].activate();
};

function createPopup(feature) {
  feature.popup = new OpenLayers.Popup(
    'pop',
    feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
    null,
    '<div>' + feature.attributes.description + '</div>',
    null,
    false,
    function() {
      controls['selector'].unselectAll();
    }
  );
  map.addPopup(feature.popup);
}

function destroyPopup(feature) {
  feature.popup.destroy();
  feature.popup = null;
}
```

*Stores* is the value returned by an ajax call containing a list of stores with latitude, longitude, address, phone, etc.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but my guess is that you were downvoted because haven't really told us what you've tried so far and why it isn't working.

Comment: You are calling createPopup and passing it a selected feature from the SelectFeature onSelect callback. This is not going to get called automatically on map load, without clicking on the feature. Also, what is stores[x]? jsFiddle always appreciated for this kind of thing, if possible. I also was not the downvoter.

Comment: stores is the value returned by an ajax call containing all stores with latitude, longitude, address, phone, etc. Is there a way I can simulate a click on the marker on the maop load that would trigger the popup ?

Comment: Is it always going to be in the same place? It looks to me like you are only using the feature passed to createPopup to grab a lat/lon. There are events that you could hook into, like zoomend (which will get called on map load), that you could use, and you could use something like the map centroid instead.

Comment: I got about 200 stores. Depending of where you are, I will point to the closest one, so it won't be the same store for everyone.

Comment: Right, but you know what this is on load, so you can pass the centroid information to a zoomend event which you can use to create the position of the initial marker?

Comment: Of course on the page load I send mark.longitude, mark.latitude, that correspont to the longitude and latitude of the closest store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You you need to select from your OpenLayers.Layer.Vector (layerVector, in your case) the feature that is closest to the centre of the map and then create a popup and add the popup to that feature, eg,

```
//select feature closest to center of map, ie, 
//find features[i] of Layer.Vector's features array.
var feature=layerVector.features[i];
addPopup(feature);

function addPopup(feature){

    var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
       'pop',
        feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
        null,
        '<div>' + feature.attributes.description + '</div>',
        null,
        true, //add a close box
        null
    );

   feature.popup = popup;
   map.addPopup(popup);
}
```

This is one possibility anyway, if I have understood the question correctly. There is a good example http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/light-basic.html that shows how to add mouse over event listener popups, and this uses the same logic, but with a feature already selected to add the popup too.